# Deleting rows that have zeros in them for multiple data sets with thousands of rows

Tags: excel, row, analysis

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I need some help with my data analysis. I am currently puzzled as to how I would delete rows that have a 0 in them for multiple datasets that have thousands of rows. I am pretty sure that I could use visual basic to do this, but as I do not have much programming experience, I was hoping that you can help.

I have attached an image where I have highlighted two examples of rows I would like to have deleted. I would like everything in red and yellow to be deleted, while everything in green and white to be left alone. If anyone has any idea of how this can be done, please help!

[Image of excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNSkJ.jpg)

Thank you a lot for your time and consideration!

Best regards,

BurekKebab

Comment: Also, please consider sharing the dataset you are working with, as this will help users to better understand how you structured your data and what the desired result is. Consider dropbox, google drive, or another cloud-based filesharing website.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me service and this will take vba.

Comment: Although not a VBA script, one (rather onerous) method is to sort by values (column-wise) then manually delete rows that you've visually checked that would be valid for deletion.

Comment: since there is data highlighted green in the same rows and the data you want deleted, it doesn't seem like you really want to delete rows. When you delete the data do you just mean you want the cells to become empty or do you expect the cells beneath to move up into the gap?

Comment: Regardless, you may find the `=product()` function helpful. It you point it at the full range of cells which might contain zero, it will return zero if any of the cells is zero. Then you only have to filter on the column with that formula and you'll find all the rows with zeroes in any of the relevant columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty trivial and can be done in several ways.

You can run the macro I provided to clear the rows (you say delete, but I think you mean clear)

This macro loops through cells in the range you want to delete, finds the zeroes, and then deletes the intersect of the row and the range you specified.

For example, I put my data in columns `A-E`

In this case, I look for zeroes in columns `C-E` or `Range("C1:E18")`

When a zero is found, I clear the row and range intersect.

The whole thing can also be done simply using filters - you could run the macro and delete rows where the 3 columns are blank.

```
Sub DeleteTheZeroes(TheRange As Range)
Dim c
For Each c In TheRange
    If c.Value = 0 Then Intersect(c.EntireRow, TheRange).Value = ""
Next c
End Sub

Sub Test()
'Change the range as needed when calling the macro
'You could also use DeleteTheZeroes Selection and highlight the data
DeleteTheZeroes Range("C1:E18")
End Sub
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for.